# How to convert a generic xml format block to properties format String from an xml file using ksh script

Tags: xml, bash, unix, properties, ksh

With the conditions:

1. I cannot use any XML parser tool as I don't have permission , read only
2. My xmllint version does not support xpath, and I cannot update it , read only
3. I dont have xmlstarlet and cannot install it

My options are limited to almost String processing.

An input parameter will be provided by the user and it will be the name of the block.

So,

let's assume

```
NAME=${USER_INPUT}
```

and we will use `$NAME` as the parameter to search the xml block that will be searched.

How can I convert a generic xml block like this in an xml file like this:

```
<block>
 <name>Bob</name>
 <address>USA</address>
 <email>bob@dogs.com</email>
 <phone>1234567</phone>
</block>

<block>
 <name>Peter</name>
 <food>France</address>
 <cell>peter@pizza.com</cell>
 <drinks>Coke</drinks>
 <car>Honda</car>
 <bike>Mountain bike</bike>
</block>
```

So the thing that I want to achieve here is to get the xml block that satisfies my search ,

for example `NAME=Bob` ;

The output of the script should be in properties file format

```
name=Bob
address=USA
email=bob@dogs.com
phone=1234567
```

A thing to consider here is that the xml format per block are different. The nodes are not the same for every xml block.

Comment: Try parsing using 'sed', yacc, or 'lex'.

Comment: Do you have python installed? I have yet to see a unix these days with out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and GNU sed:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="Bob"
sed -n '/name>'${NAME}'/,/<\/block>/s/.*<\(.*\)>\(.*\)<.*/\1=\2/p' file.xml
```

Output:

```
name=Bob
address=USA
email=bob@dogs.com
phone=1234567
```

Comment: where do I place $NAME ?

Comment: Save this script e.g. as script.sh, make it executable with `cmod +x script.sh` and run it with `./script.sh "NAME=Bob"`

Comment: can it be done that $NAME=Bob is inside the script? My design will be put in jeopardy if I do that. I execute scripts using a Java coded application.